# Why is the --simple-prompt command not working?

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm just starting with Ruby, so please bear with me.  The problem is that when I enter `--simple-prompt` into irb on OS 10.10.3 terminal, I don't get the simple prompt, I get an error message:

```
irb(main):001:0> --simple-prompt
NameError: undefined local variable or method `simple' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I'm assuming that the following problem is related to the above in that `-v`, `-cw`, etc. don't seem to work either.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about passing flags to commands vs issuing statements in a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

To start `irb` with the `--simple-prompt` option enabled, pass it in like so:

```
$ irb --simple-prompt
>>
```

Then you should be able to execute Ruby code.

```
>> puts "hello world!"
hello world!
=> nil
>>
```

Comment: That didn't work, but irb --simple-prompt did, but only from the unix command line.  Am I to understand that this will work only on the unix command line and not from the irb interpreter?  (Edit.  I was able to execute Ruby code before, but not, as mentioned --simple-prompt or -e, -v, etc.)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear, the `$` indicates that command should be entered from the unix command line.

Comment: Yes, switches such as `--simple-prompt` or `-v` can only be invoked on startup. Depending on the program, there may be a way to change them afterwards, but `irb` does not provide such an interface for the prompt option.

Comment: Not true @messanjah the `@prompt` variable can be changed, and in fact, changing it in your `~/.irbrc` is not a rare thing.  I guess the "interface" is IRB itself, or Ruby... :)

Comment: No worries.  Now I'm still not able to run, for example, -v, with or without simple-prompt activated.  If you've already addressed this problem when you wrote "You seem to be confused about passing flags..." then I'm afraid I'm still confused.  (Thanks for your answer and for the ref. to REPL.)

Comment: `-v` is just another flag that `irb` accepts. It tells the program (`irb`) to print its version number and exit. It is not intended to be run inside the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `--simple-prompt` is a command line option to toggle the prompt.

You can see this by typing `exit` to get out of IRB and then typing

`irb --help`

Which gives you something like this:

```
Usage:  irb.rb [options] [programfile] [arguments]
  -f            Suppress read of ~/.irbrc
  -m            Bc mode (load mathn, fraction or matrix are available)
  -d                Set $DEBUG to true (same as `ruby -d')
  -r load-module    Same as `ruby -r'
  -I path           Specify $LOAD_PATH directory
  -U                Same as `ruby -U`
  -E enc            Same as `ruby -E`
  -w                Same as `ruby -w`
  -W[level=2]       Same as `ruby -W`
  --context-mode n  Set n[0-3] to method to create Binding Object,
                    when new workspace was created
  --echo            Show result(default)
  --noecho          Don't show result
  --inspect     Use `inspect' for output (default except for bc mode)
  --noinspect       Don't use inspect for output
  --readline        Use Readline extension module
  --noreadline      Don't use Readline extension module
  --prompt prompt-mode/--prompt-mode prompt-mode
            Switch prompt mode. Pre-defined prompt modes are
            `default', `simple', `xmp' and `inf-ruby'
  --inf-ruby-mode   Use prompt appropriate for inf-ruby-mode on emacs.
            Suppresses --readline.
  --sample-book-mode/--simple-prompt
                    Simple prompt mode
  --noprompt        No prompt mode
  --single-irb      Share self with sub-irb.
  --tracer          Display trace for each execution of commands.
  --back-trace-limit n
            Display backtrace top n and tail n. The default
            value is 16.
  --irb_debug n     Set internal debug level to n (not for popular use)
  --verbose         Show details
  --noverbose       Don't show details
  -v, --version     Print the version of irb
  -h, --help        Print help
  --                Separate options of irb from the list of command-line args
```

The `--sample-book-mode` or `--simple-prompt` is used in a command like this:

`irb --simple-prompt`

You can also do:

`irb --prompt simple`

But you can not do these things inside of IRB.

There is a way to change the prompt inside IRB, though, by changing the `@prompt` variable.